# Prove $n!>n^2$ for $n>3$

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm aware that induction is necessary. I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now. I'm having a hard time understanding how to apply the inductive hypothesis to the inequality to arrive at the $P_{n+1}$ step.

Base case clearly holds as $24 > 16$.

Assume $P_n: n!>n^2, n\geq 4$ holds.

$(n+1)n! > (n+1) n^2$

$(n+1)! > (n+1) n^2 $ <--- needs to be in form $(n+1)! > (n+1)^2$.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Induction isn't necessary, it's one of many ways. What's left in your proof is to show that $n^2 \geqslant n+1$.

Comment: The exercise requires that induction is used. It is prefaced with, "The principle of mathematical can be extended as follows. A list $P_m,P_{m+1},\cdots$ of propositions is true provided (i) $P_m$ is true, (ii) $P_{n+1}$ is true whenever $P_n$ is true and $n \geq m$.

Comment: It would seem that this user outsources his third-year math homework to stackexchange.  The community might want to think about whether encouraging this is prudent.

Comment: Not proposing to close, just linking to the [node](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396) of this network of duplicates. This post here is older, the node has existing duplicate links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: Show that $n^2\ge n+1$, then multiply that inequality by $n+1$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I knew subconciously that this is what I was missing. I just wasn't aware that it was the next step in the proof.

Comment: @Neurax: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Induction isn't necessary. For $n>3$, $\displaystyle n!\ge n(n-1)(n-2)\ge 2n(n-1)>2n\frac{n}{2}=n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with:

$$n(n! - 2) > 1$$

Note that this inequality holds, because $n \geq 2$ and $n! \geq 6$

$$n\times n! > 2n + 1$$
$$n \times n! + n! > n^2 + 2n + 1$$
$$n!(n+1) > n^2 + 2n + 1$$
$$(n+1)! > (n+1)^2$$

Using little algebra we finally get what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(n-1)(n-2)-n=n^2-4n+2=(n-2)^2-2$

If $n\gt 3$ then $(n-2)^2\ge 4\gt 2$ so that $(n-2)^2-2\gt 0$ whence $(n-1)(n-2)\gt n$

So that for $n\gt 3$ we have $$n!\ge n\cdot (n-1)(n-2)\gt n\cdot n=n^2$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $$n!> n^2$$ for $n>3$

or,

$$(n-1)!>n$$ for $n>3$

But what is $(n-1)!$ ? It is the number of ways ordering $n$ people around a circle, and the inequality is follows.